# Safari redirect to App not working

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, mobile-safari

I have an app on my iPhone , that i am trying to open . Lynda.com. 
I Tap the Lynda.com app on your device to launch it.
Ignore the user name and password fields on the login screen and instead tap on the button labeled web portal log in
On the web portal access screen, enter < company name >in the URL box.
I am  directed to Usher ( my company's internal authentication )

After successful authentication , i had to be redirected back to Lynda.com App ..

This works on several of my coworkers phone , but on my phone after the authentication is successful I am still on Lynda.com safari browser .

Things i tried:

- Updating my IOS on phone to the same version that a current working phone is on ( latest update 9.3.3)
- deleting safari cache
- deleted and reinstalled Lynda.com app and retried ..

### Any suggestion?

Indu

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution. Private mode was turned on in Safari. When I turn it off, the browser redirect works and opens the page in the target app. When it private mode there is no pop for "Open in app".